# Visualize structured streaming writeStream output in Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-visualization, spark-structured-streaming

I have my Structured Streaming scala application in Intellij.

After getting the result in writeStream() form using:

```
val streamingDS = data
  .writeStream
  .format("json")
  .option("checkpointLocation", path)
  .option("path",path)
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

How do I visualize the writeStream output in real time in Intellij using the `display()` function capability as described here ? https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#visualizations-in-scala

display() function doesn't seem to be available in Intellij. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** `display`-like feature is not available outside a notebook environment like Databricks.

The closest would be to use `console` format to print out the rows to console.

```
val streamingDS = data
  .writeStream
  .format("console") // <-- use console
  .option("checkpointLocation", path)
  .option("path",path)
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Ok, what's the best way for now to visualize the output generated in write stream form?

Answer (score 0):

`display` is Databricks function, it's not available when just using Spark in any other environment.

However, you can use `console sink` to debug output of streaming, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#starting-streaming-queries for details.

You'll have to change code to something like

```
data
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```